# trying to access object data in angular 6 property id is missing in type object

Tags: typescript, angular6

i've created an interface which looks like this:-

```
export interface Recipe {
    id: number;
    likes: number[];
}
```

and my component which looks like this:-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {RecipeService } from '../../recipe.service';
import {Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {Recipe} from '../../recipe.interface';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-recent-blog-recipes',
  templateUrl: './recent-blog-recipes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recent-blog-recipes.component.scss'],

})
export class RecentBlogRecipesComponent implements OnInit {

    recipes$: Object;
  likes$ : Recipe[];

  constructor(private data: RecipeService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getUserId().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.likes$.push(data);
        console.log(this.likes$);
        },
      error => console.log(error)
    )
  }
}
```

and when i compile it,i get this error :

```
ERROR in src/app/welcome/recent-blog-recipes/recent-blog-recipes.component.ts(52,26): error TS2345: Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Recipe'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
    Property 'id' is missing in type 'Object'.
```

how is this possible and i have the id in the interface? also my logged data from the object looks like this before i try to push it in the "likes$[]" array:-

{id: 1 , likes:[1,2,12]}

any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `likes$` is `Recipe[]`, you need to ensure that return type of `getUserId` is Observable of `any` or any other type assignable to `Recipe`.

```
public getUserId(): Observable<Recipe>{
 return this.http.get<Recipe>('...');
}
```